# How to scrape breakfast menu?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Let us consider following site : [Breakfast](https://dcsd.nutrislice.com/menu/meadow-view/breakfast/2023-04-14)

Here I want to take simple Fruit Variety,let us see    code  which corresponds  table :
[image]

I have tried following code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ="https://dcsd.nutrislice.com/menu/meadow-view/breakfast/2023-04-14"
doc =requests.get(url).content
tags =BeautifulSoup(doc,'html.parser')
# print(tags.prettify())
parent = tags.find("body").find("ul")
text = list(parent.descendants)
print(text)
```

this code was taken from given site : [read ul tag](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/beautifulsoup-find-all-li-in-ul/)

but when i have run got following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\get_content.py", line 8, in <module>
    text = list(parent.descendants)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

maybe it is based on  javascript and data is hidden? could you  give me some hint please?

Comment: As you would have noticed when you `print(tags.prettify())`, the contents of the `<body>` are not provided in the initial download, so your selector fails. The page contains Javascript which presumably downloads and renders the items separately.

Comment: If you load that site with your browser's developer tools open, then the network panel will show all resources that are loaded. There will likely be an XHR request in the list, which will load the data as a JSON document or similar.

Comment: and how to do XHR request?

Answer (score 1):

As well mentioned by @motto:

> As you would have noticed when you print(tags.prettify()), the contents of the  are not provided in the initial download, so your selector fails. The page contains Javascript which presumably downloads and renders the items separately...
>
> If you load that site with your browser's developer tools open, then
> the network panel will show all resources that are loaded. There will
> likely be an XHR request in the list, which will load the data as a
> JSON document or similar.

To answer your question `and how to do XHR request?`  the same way you did before, but using the api resource as url.

###### Example

```
import requests

url = 'https://dcsd.api.nutrislice.com/menu/api/weeks/school/meadow-view/menu-type/breakfast/2023/04/14/'
week_data = requests.get(url).json()

for d in week_data['days']:
    if d['date'] == '2023-04-14':
        print(d['menu_items'])
```

###### Output

```
[{'id': 69639515, 'date': None, 'position': 0, 'is_section_title': False, 'bold': False, 'featured': False, 'text': '', 'no_line_break': False, 'blank_line': False, 'food': {'id': 1106050, 'name': 'Peach Yogurt Smoothie', 'description': 'No sugar added! A great way to get a serving of fruit and dairy!', 'subtext': '', 'image_url': 'https://assets.nutrislice.com/asset/serve/image/JPG/187198/thumbnail2', 'hoverpic_url': 'https://assets.nutrislice.com/asset/serve/image/JPG/187198/thumbnail', 'price': 2.25, 'ingredients': '', 'food_category': 'entree', 'food_highlight_message': None, 'file_url': '', 'download_label': "View Manufacturer's Label", 'rounded_nutrition_info': {'calories': 125.0, 'g_fat': 0.5, 'g_saturated_fat': None, 'g_trans_fat': None, 'mg_cholesterol': 5.0, 'g_carbs': 35.0, 'g_sugar': 20.0, 'g_added_sugar': None, 'mg_sodium': 70.0, 'mg_potassium': None, 'g_fiber': 3.0, 'g_protein': 5.0, 'mg_iron': None, 'mg_calcium': None, 'mg_vitamin_c': None, 'iu_vitamin_a': None, 're_vitamin_a': None, 'mg_vitamin_d': None}, 'serving_size_info': {'serving_size_amount': '1', 'serving_size_unit': 'Smoothie'}, 'has_nutrition_info': True, 'icons': {'food_icons': [{'id': 1574, 'synced_name': 'Milk', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'class_name': 'milk-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 1, 'is_filter': True, 'is_highlight': False, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'milk', 'icon_slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', '_synced_name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'sort_order': 0, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 243}], 'myplate_icons': []}, 'icons_approved': True, 'nested_foods': [], 'aggregated_data': {'price_adjustment': 0.0, 'icons_approved': True, 'food_icons': [], 'calories': 0.0}, 'ordering_enabled': True, 'food_sizes': [], 'ds_calories_override': '', 'synced_id': '', 'sync_placeholder': None, 'has_options_or_sides': False, 'digest': 'QYezhm/8RBw7EsKFMtXNQaNOVeR2zJzAORxBXvaODxvRZdATKOpe4ZLZ/HaNmRyTvka9372RQBerboxXWRIC/g==', 'pos_item_id': '', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'has_subfoods': False, 'meal_plan_price': None, 'use_custom_sizes': False}, 'is_holiday': False, 'food_list': None, 'station_id': None, 'is_station_header': False, 'station_is_collapsible': False, 'image': '', 'image_description': None, 'image_alt': None, 'image_thumbnail': '', 'category': 'entree', 'price': 2.25, 'serving_size': None, 'serving_size_amount': 1.0, 'serving_size_unit': 'Smoothie', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'menu_id': 78728}, {'id': 69639516, 'date': None, 'position': 1, 'is_section_title': False, 'bold': False, 'featured': False, 'text': '', 'no_line_break': False, 'blank_line': False, 'food': {'id': 663274, 'name': 'Cheez-its', 'description': '', 'subtext': '', 'image_url': None, 'hoverpic_url': None, 'price': 0.5, 'ingredients': '', 'food_category': '', 'food_highlight_message': None, 'file_url': '', 'download_label': "View Manufacturer's Label", 'rounded_nutrition_info': {'calories': 101.0, 'g_fat': 3.5, 'g_saturated_fat': 1.0, 'g_trans_fat': 0, 'mg_cholesterol': 4.0, 'g_carbs': 14.0, 'g_sugar': 0.0, 'g_added_sugar': 0.0, 'mg_sodium': 152.0, 'mg_potassium': None, 'g_fiber': 1.0, 'g_protein': 3.0, 'mg_iron': None, 'mg_calcium': None, 'mg_vitamin_c': None, 'iu_vitamin_a': None, 're_vitamin_a': None, 'mg_vitamin_d': None}, 'serving_size_info': {'serving_size_amount': '1', 'serving_size_unit': 'bag'}, 'has_nutrition_info': True, 'icons': {'food_icons': [{'id': 1574, 'synced_name': 'Milk', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'class_name': 'milk-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 1, 'is_filter': True, 'is_highlight': False, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'milk', 'icon_slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', '_synced_name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'sort_order': 0, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 243}, {'id': 1576, 'synced_name': 'Wheat', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.wheat', 'name': 'Wheat', 'help_text': 'This contains wheat', 'class_name': 'wheat-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 1, 'is_filter': True, 'is_highlight': False, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'wheat', 'icon_slug': 'default.wheat', 'name': 'Wheat', '_synced_name': 'Wheat', 'help_text': 'This contains wheat', 'sort_order': 2, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 243}, {'id': 1577, 'synced_name': 'Soy', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.soy', 'name': 'Soy', 'help_text': 'This contains soy', 'class_name': 'soy-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 1, 'is_filter': True, 'is_highlight': False, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'soy', 'icon_slug': 'default.soy', 'name': 'Soy', '_synced_name': 'Soy', 'help_text': 'This contains soy', 'sort_order': 3, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 243}], 'myplate_icons': [{'id': 1584, 'synced_name': 'Grain', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'myplate.grain', 'name': 'Grain', 'help_text': 'This contains grain', 'class_name': 'grain-group'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 4, 'behavior': 1, 'is_filter': True, 'is_highlight': False, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'grain', 'icon_slug': 'myplate.grain', 'name': 'Grain', '_synced_name': 'Grain', 'help_text': 'This contains grain', 'sort_order': 2, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 244}]}, 'icons_approved': True, 'nested_foods': [], 'aggregated_data': {'price_adjustment': 0.0, 'icons_approved': True, 'food_icons': [], 'calories': 0.0}, 'ordering_enabled': True, 'food_sizes': [], 'ds_calories_override': '', 'synced_id': '', 'sync_placeholder': None, 'has_options_or_sides': False, 'digest': 'H30WEU95MHFDqcf5rsycD9hJT+G67Qtfrh5wPd1GIptAKCOr8lFeoAl6nGJ7sc8xaup1l6SI81qBBBucgmYAbA==', 'pos_item_id': '5b96dd19cef0402c99e00b16c2d0369b', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'has_subfoods': False, 'meal_plan_price': None, 'use_custom_sizes': False}, 'is_holiday': False, 'food_list': None, 'station_id': None, 'is_station_header': False, 'station_is_collapsible': False, 'image': '', 'image_description': None, 'image_alt': None, 'image_thumbnail': '', 'category': '', 'price': 0.5, 'serving_size': None, 'serving_size_amount': 1.0, 'serving_size_unit': 'bag', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'menu_id': 78728}, {'id': 69639517, 'date': None, 'position': 2, 'is_section_title': False, 'bold': False, 'featured': False, 'text': '', 'no_line_break': False, 'blank_line': False, 'food': {'id': 443319, 'name': 'Fruit Variety (see below)', 'description': 'See sidebar for all possible fruit offerings served throughout the year.', 'subtext': '', 'image_url': 'https://client-food-images.nutrislice.com/images/b5/b5Y8U2fJM953SoxnF5ut38/1451324860_056222__fruitvariety.jpg.1024x0_q85.jpg', 'hoverpic_url': 'https://client-food-images.nutrislice.com/images/b5/b5Y8U2fJM953SoxnF5ut38/1451324860_056222__fruitvariety.jpg.220x0_q85.jpg', 'price': None, 'ingredients': '', 'food_category': '', 'food_highlight_message': None, 'file_url': '', 'download_label': "View Manufacturer's Label", 'rounded_nutrition_info': {'calories': None, 'g_fat': None, 'g_saturated_fat': None, 'g_trans_fat': None, 'mg_cholesterol': None, 'g_carbs': None, 'g_sugar': None, 'g_added_sugar': None, 'mg_sodium': None, 'mg_potassium': None, 'g_fiber': None, 'g_protein': None, 'mg_iron': None, 'mg_calcium': None, 'mg_vitamin_c': None, 'iu_vitamin_a': None, 're_vitamin_a': None, 'mg_vitamin_d': None}, 'serving_size_info': {'serving_size_amount': '1', 'serving_size_unit': None}, 'has_nutrition_info': False, 'icons': {'food_icons': [{'id': 7890, 'synced_name': 'Gluten Free', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.gluten-free', 'name': 'Gluten Free', 'help_text': 'This is gluten-free!', 'class_name': 'gluten-free-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 2, 'is_filter': False, 'is_highlight': True, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'gluten-free', 'icon_slug': 'default.gluten-free', 'name': 'Gluten Free', '_synced_name': 'Gluten Free', 'help_text': '', 'sort_order': 0, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 1209}, {'id': 7891, 'synced_name': 'Vegetarian', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.vegetarian', 'name': 'Vegetarian', 'help_text': 'This is meat-free and suitable for vegetarians', 'class_name': 'vegetarian-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 2, 'is_filter': False, 'is_highlight': True, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'vegetarian', 'icon_slug': 'default.vegetarian', 'name': 'Vegetarian', '_synced_name': 'Vegetarian', 'help_text': '', 'sort_order': 1, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 1209}], 'myplate_icons': []}, 'icons_approved': True, 'nested_foods': [], 'aggregated_data': {'price_adjustment': 0, 'icons_approved': True, 'food_icons': [], 'calories': 0}, 'ordering_enabled': False, 'food_sizes': [], 'ds_calories_override': '', 'synced_id': '', 'sync_placeholder': None, 'has_options_or_sides': False, 'digest': 'BBklS/TQfeH3Y4xx+aKTVur4YV0I5Ou8uHwG6cbkbPiBb9yv70655kj0Qr52OU0pxmZ9nRNpU+f9Kn6McsMc0w==', 'pos_item_id': '', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'has_subfoods': False, 'meal_plan_price': None, 'use_custom_sizes': False}, 'is_holiday': False, 'food_list': None, 'station_id': None, 'is_station_header': False, 'station_is_collapsible': False, 'image': '', 'image_description': None, 'image_alt': None, 'image_thumbnail': '', 'category': '', 'price': None, 'serving_size': None, 'serving_size_amount': None, 'serving_size_unit': None, 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'menu_id': 78728}, {'id': 69639518, 'date': None, 'position': 3, 'is_section_title': False, 'bold': False, 'featured': False, 'text': '', 'no_line_break': False, 'blank_line': False, 'food': {'id': 443241, 'name': 'Milk, White (Dairy Pure)', 'description': "Whether it's white or flavored, milk comes packed with nine essential nutrients like calcium, vitamin D, and phosphorus. And our chocolate milk is fat free! It's a great way for your student to power up on some serious nutrition!", 'subtext': '', 'image_url': 'https://assets.nutrislice.com/asset/serve/5464/thumbnail2', 'hoverpic_url': 'https://assets.nutrislice.com/asset/serve/5464/thumbnail', 'price': 1.25, 'ingredients': '', 'food_category': '', 'food_highlight_message': None, 'file_url': '', 'download_label': "View Manufacturer's Label", 'rounded_nutrition_info': {'calories': 110.0, 'g_fat': 2.5, 'g_saturated_fat': 1.5, 'g_trans_fat': 0, 'mg_cholesterol': 10.0, 'g_carbs': 13.0, 'g_sugar': 12.0, 'g_added_sugar': None, 'mg_sodium': 130.0, 'mg_potassium': None, 'g_fiber': 0.0, 'g_protein': 8.0, 'mg_iron': 0.0, 'mg_calcium': 0.0, 'mg_vitamin_c': 0.0, 'iu_vitamin_a': 0.0, 're_vitamin_a': None, 'mg_vitamin_d': None}, 'serving_size_info': {'serving_size_amount': '8', 'serving_size_unit': 'fl oz'}, 'has_nutrition_info': True, 'icons': {'food_icons': [{'id': 1574, 'synced_name': 'Milk', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'class_name': 'milk-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 1, 'is_filter': True, 'is_highlight': False, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'milk', 'icon_slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', '_synced_name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'sort_order': 0, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 243}, {'id': 7890, 'synced_name': 'Gluten Free', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.gluten-free', 'name': 'Gluten Free', 'help_text': 'This is gluten-free!', 'class_name': 'gluten-free-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 2, 'is_filter': False, 'is_highlight': True, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'gluten-free', 'icon_slug': 'default.gluten-free', 'name': 'Gluten Free', '_synced_name': 'Gluten Free', 'help_text': '', 'sort_order': 0, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 1209}, {'id': 7891, 'synced_name': 'Vegetarian', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.vegetarian', 'name': 'Vegetarian', 'help_text': 'This is meat-free and suitable for vegetarians', 'class_name': 'vegetarian-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 2, 'is_filter': False, 'is_highlight': True, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'vegetarian', 'icon_slug': 'default.vegetarian', 'name': 'Vegetarian', '_synced_name': 'Vegetarian', 'help_text': '', 'sort_order': 1, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 1209}], 'myplate_icons': []}, 'icons_approved': True, 'nested_foods': [], 'aggregated_data': {'price_adjustment': 0.0, 'icons_approved': True, 'food_icons': [], 'calories': 0.0}, 'ordering_enabled': False, 'food_sizes': [], 'ds_calories_override': '', 'synced_id': '3fb482b6d6ec41a791956c90442a2b55', 'sync_placeholder': None, 'has_options_or_sides': False, 'digest': '8IA6VYWEilY+leApissqZFLEuwcKO2rSabdtaD6HztgkZgb8Ar04nA3uOreFXQrsxFjqUHduwAqPw7L7v7AVSQ==', 'pos_item_id': '', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'has_subfoods': False, 'meal_plan_price': None, 'use_custom_sizes': False}, 'is_holiday': False, 'food_list': None, 'station_id': None, 'is_station_header': False, 'station_is_collapsible': False, 'image': '', 'image_description': None, 'image_alt': None, 'image_thumbnail': '', 'category': '', 'price': 1.25, 'serving_size': None, 'serving_size_amount': 8.0, 'serving_size_unit': 'fl oz', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'menu_id': 78728}, {'id': 69639519, 'date': None, 'position': 4, 'is_section_title': False, 'bold': False, 'featured': False, 'text': '', 'no_line_break': False, 'blank_line': False, 'food': {'id': 1216339, 'name': 'Milk, Chocolate TruMoo', 'description': 'Nutrient rich milk combined with chocolate, a perfect combination!', 'subtext': '', 'image_url': None, 'hoverpic_url': None, 'price': 1.25, 'ingredients': '', 'food_category': '', 'food_highlight_message': None, 'file_url': '', 'download_label': "View Manufacturer's Label", 'rounded_nutrition_info': {'calories': 120.0, 'g_fat': None, 'g_saturated_fat': None, 'g_trans_fat': None, 'mg_cholesterol': 5.0, 'g_carbs': 20.0, 'g_sugar': 18.0, 'g_added_sugar': None, 'mg_sodium': 180.0, 'mg_potassium': None, 'g_fiber': None, 'g_protein': 8.0, 'mg_iron': None, 'mg_calcium': None, 'mg_vitamin_c': None, 'iu_vitamin_a': None, 're_vitamin_a': None, 'mg_vitamin_d': None}, 'serving_size_info': {'serving_size_amount': '1', 'serving_size_unit': 'each'}, 'has_nutrition_info': True, 'icons': {'food_icons': [{'id': 1574, 'synced_name': 'Milk', 'enabled': True, 'sprite': {'slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'class_name': 'milk-icon'}, 'custom_icon_url': None, 'custom_icon': None, 'type': 1, 'behavior': 1, 'is_filter': True, 'is_highlight': False, 'is_digital_signage_only': False, 'slug': 'milk', 'icon_slug': 'default.milk', 'name': 'Milk', '_synced_name': 'Milk', 'help_text': 'This contains milk', 'sort_order': 0, '_enabled': True, 'food_icon_group': 243}], 'myplate_icons': []}, 'icons_approved': True, 'nested_foods': [], 'aggregated_data': {'price_adjustment': 0.0, 'icons_approved': True, 'food_icons': [], 'calories': 0.0}, 'ordering_enabled': True, 'food_sizes': [], 'ds_calories_override': '', 'synced_id': '', 'sync_placeholder': None, 'has_options_or_sides': False, 'digest': '+MBJQtx3vh/Z2h79hDorHOH4T/g4OCfsocMLRIlULGahDi789E516UtRgGWhhEYnToRXeW0WlyKUwiolwQFbdg==', 'pos_item_id': '', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'has_subfoods': False, 'meal_plan_price': None, 'use_custom_sizes': False}, 'is_holiday': False, 'food_list': None, 'station_id': None, 'is_station_header': False, 'station_is_collapsible': False, 'image': '', 'image_description': None, 'image_alt': None, 'image_thumbnail': '', 'category': '', 'price': 1.25, 'serving_size': None, 'serving_size_amount': 1.0, 'serving_size_unit': 'each', 'smart_recipe_id': None, 'menu_id': 78728}]
```

---

An alternative would be to use `selenium` that mimics the browser and renders also dynamically provided content - Be aware that there is a consent layer for cookies that has to be clicked. Used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here, to locate the button by `button.primary`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'https://dcsd.nutrislice.com/menu/meadow-view/breakfast/2023-04-14'
driver.get(url)
# driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.primary'))).click()
for e in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.food-link'))):
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: could you please explain me what does  button.primary?  for instance if  i use this code for accessing  this link :https://www.flashscore.ge/football/italy/serie-a/standings/#/UcnjEEGS/live does it takes  table from here?

Comment: Be aware that there is a consent layer for cookies that has to be clicked. Used [`css selectors`][1] here, to locate the button by `button.primary`. Concerning your second question it could give you the tables, but has to be adjusted a bit, to match the elements on this different website.

Comment: i have tried  a lot of stuff, but always get confuse

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if it concern the flashscore.ge it would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus.